# Examples where the cup product is not an isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology

If I understood correctly, it seems that for any smooth complex algebraic variety X, the cup product induces the following map on the singular homology groups with values in $\mathbb Z$:
$$\bigwedge^n H^1(X,\mathbb Z) \rightarrow H^n(X,\mathbb Z).$$

Is this map always an isomorphism if $X$ is a smooth complex algebraic variety? Is there any counterexample where this map fails to be surjective?

Comment: $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{C})$ will do (because $H^1=0$).

Comment: @Roland Many thanks for your answer. I am a bit confused: I thought that $H^i(\mathbb P^n, \mathbb Z)$ was isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$ for all $i\in\{0,\ldots, n\}$. In the case of $\mathbb P^n$, isn't its cohomology ring isomorphic to its Chow ring?

Comment: No, algebraic cycles live in even cohomology degree. In other words, the natural map is $CH^*(X)\rightarrow H^{2*}(X)$. This is true that this map is an isomorphism for $\mathbb{P}^n$. But the odd cohomology part of $\mathbb{P}^n$ is zero.

Comment: @Roland Oh, ok. Thanks a lot, it clarifies a lot of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, the only examples I know where this holds are abelian varieties; in this case $X$ is topologically a torus, and we in fact have $H^k(X, \mathbb{Z}) \cong \bigwedge^k H^1(X, \mathbb{Z})$.

As Roland says in the comments, $\mathbb{CP}^n$ for $n \ge 1$ is a counterexample.

Comment: I wonder if this condition (that cohomology is the exterior algebra over $H^1$) in fact characterises either tori among compact manifolds, or abelian varieties among projective varieties. I can't think of other examples in either case, but I am always glad to be enlightened...

Comment: @Nefertiti: in the manifold case I'm worried about the possibility of taking connected sums with integral homology spheres.

Comment: Good point; I'm still curious about the case of projective varieties.

Comment: OK, it seems that the answer is _yes_ for projective varieties, or more generally Kaehler manifolds: the only ones whose cohomology is the exterior algebra over $H^1$ are abelian varieties (resp. tori). A reference is http://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.01043v1.pdf, which credits Catanese with the result. That paper investigates the more general problem of classifying _rational_ cohomology tori --- it is full of nice results!